# Add Date/Time when adding product to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime

I have tried to Google this so I didn't have to ask, as i'm sure this is a simple task...

I am building an E-commerce site and would like to add the date and time a product is added into the product database?

Apologies if this is simple, but i have researched everywhere else first.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having? Have you tried using the built-in functions? `date('d-m-Y');` or [DateTime class](http://php.net/datetime)?

Comment: Shane, that's a good question, but there are a lot of different solutions. If you can give us more information we can try to suggest ones which fit your situation. For example, are you writing raw PHP, or are you using a framework? Which library are you using to talk to MySQL?

Comment: Please check http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: @pjmorse - I'm not sure as i am new to all this. I am writing raw PHP

Comment: Then you can use php date functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can just be part of your database architecture:

```
ALTER TABLE  `products` ADD  `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This will automatically add a timestamp to the column `created` whenever a row is created. For more information, try this: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Obviously, in this case the table is called `products` and you would need to change it to whatever your table name is.

**UPDATE**
To update all existing records at the same time, just run:

```
UPDATE `products` SET `created` = NOW()
```

If you want to be more specific use:

```
UPDATE `products` SET `created` = NOW() WHERE `created` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This is the best approach. Let the database do the work, don't worry about doing it in PHP.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, All previous products now show as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` Is there a query to change all these to `2013-09-10 14:25:27`?

Comment: @Shane See my update. Just a simple matter of setting all records to the current date/time. If you specifically want that timestamp, just change `NOW()` to `'2013-09-10 14:25:27'`

Comment: @BrendanBullen - Fantastic, Thanks so much. Finally (sorry) Can you help with this, I have a list which should show the 10 newest products, how would I now do this (now i have date and time recorded) Here is my current code `$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 1,10")`

Comment: @Shane You need to order the results in your query. Try: `$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,10")`

Comment: @Shane Also, since you're just starting out, it would be best not to go down a bad road as far as development goes. now is the chance to avoid using `mysql_*` functions like `mysql_query`. They are deprecated and there are better alternatives. Check out this question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Comment: @BrendanBullen - I don't suppose you have the queryto hand for adding a new column to the database do you

Comment: @Shane My answer above is the query for adding a column (in this case it adds a column called `created`). It very much depends on the type of column you require. You should read this for more information on altering a table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Thanks @BrendanBullen I am grateful for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Method1 : Pass the Current DateTime as parameter to the Insert

Method2: Set the default value for the date time column in  *Product*  table